# my character disappears when i stand still UE5

Tags: unreal-engine5, blueprint

Hello Everyone i need help...

It plays a 2d game over the blueprint, but when my character doesn't move, it becomes invisible. I tried all kinds of links, but no results, I would appreciate if you can help, thank you, respect.

**---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtrYa.png)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately 2D in Unreal is very "poorly done", so errors like this are normal, every 2D component is rendered only on one side, unless you configure the material to be visible on both sides, something that should be standard.  To solve this just try to rotate your character 90/180° or edit the sprite material.  (Forgive me for any typos, I'm using Google Translate)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, can i get a chance to contact you?

Comment: Yes, i have a discord, Frytinhas#5071

Comment: i cant add you, Egee#7824 You can add me.

Comment: Ok, i send a invite